# SQL Query to pick data from a certain time range

Tags: vb.net

I have two fields in my DB.
1) Invoice_Date and Invoice_Time

They recored date and time from my invoices.

I want to pick data under two queries:
1)Using From_Time DateTimePicker and To_Time DateTimePicker (they display as 19:20:18 PM)
Here I want to pick data for say between 13:10:12 PM to 18:10:20 PM, no matter what date it is.

2) Secondly I want data for a specific data range (from datatimepickers) to specific time range (time datatimepickers)

Please advise how to do it.

I tried:

Where InvTime between @Time1 and @Time2

But it did not generate any data, while data is there for the given time range.

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: What is your current query?

Comment: which DB you are using?

Comment: Please show your relevant code (SQL and VB.NET).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if I understand you correctly you want you want to find all invoices between a start and stop time based on your invoice time. I will assume the invoice time is a date time field that may have different date values.

```
Where CONVERT(DATETIME(CONVERT(CHAR(5),invoice_time)) BETWEEN @StartTime AND @StopTime
```

You could also do the same conversion to your start and stop time. The key here is that all the datetime values you are comparing have the same date  Since all we care about is time the date will just be the default.